# How to replace a number in a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a URL that always ends with the number 30. I want to replace that with another number 100. I am not sure if regex is the best option and if so, how to do it?
This is my attempt, but I am looking for something more professional that would work in any situation and only change the last bit of the URL that has 30.

```
let URL = "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5c/5a/a0/5c5aa0fd-978e-b038-3918-f6127f97295e/source/30x30bb.jpg";
URL.replace("/([30])\w+/g", "100");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `URL = URL.replace('30x30', '100x100')` ?

Comment: @charlietfl has a great idea.  I might tweak it a little like this: `URL.replace('/30x30', '/100x100')` just to decrease the risk of "30x30" showing up elsewhere, such as in the string that looks like a hash.

Comment: @charlietfl `I have a URL that always ends with the number 30. I want to replace that with another number 100.` i guess op is talking about only last one not both

Comment: Actually I am talking about both. My bad. I just dont want it to be replaced if 30 is somweher wlese in the URL like `http://somewebsite30.com/30x30.jpg`

Comment: @DannyBoy what if the url is something like `http://somewebsite30.com/40x30.jpg` or `http://somewebsite30.com/30x40.jpg`  ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Good question. The API am getting URLs from, only provide square sizes. So both number s will be always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ensure that you're only replacing in the portion after the last slash with something like this:

```
var URL = "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5c/5a/a0/5c5aa0fd-978e-b038-3918-f6127f97295e/source/30x30bb.jpg";
var urlFixer = (url) => {
  splitArray = url.split("/");
  splitArray[splitArray.length-1] = splitArray[splitArray.length-1].replace("30x30","100x100");
  return splitArray.join("/");
}

console.log(urlFixer(URL));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this regex

```
\/30x30([a-z]*\.\w+)$
```

[image]

---

```js
let URL = "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5c/5a/a0/5c5aa0fd-978e-b038-3918-f6127f97295e/source/30x30bb.jpg";

let replace30 = (url) =>{
  return url.replace(/\/30x30([a-z]*\.\w+)$/g, "/100x100"+ "$1")
}

console.log(replace30(URL))
console.log(replace30('http:hello.example.com/400x500bb.jpg'))
console.log(replace30('http:hello.example.com/source/helloworld.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let URL = "https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music/v4/5c/5a/a0/5c5aa0fd-978e-b038-3918-f6127f97295e/source/30x30bb.jpg";

let last_index=URL.lastIndexOf('/');
let substring=URL.substring(last_index + 1);
let replaced=substring.replace(/30/g,"100");
let newURL=URL.substr(0, last_index+1) + replaced;

console.log(newURL);
```